# Refresh a div after an AJAX request

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, ajax, laravel

I have a notifications panel and when the user clicks the cross to delete a notification I want just the DIV to refresh so it will throw away the old notification and refresh with the current ones, here i what I have now, it refreshes but all the data disappears and shows nothing but the box.

**Screenshots**

Before:

[image]

After:

[image]

**HTML**

```
<div id="messageboxcon">
  @php
     $usersid2 = Auth::id();
     $usersalert2 = DB::table('notifications')->where('userid', $usersid2)->orderBy('created_at', 'desc')->get();
  @endphp

  <h3 style="color: gray; 
      font-weight: 100; 
      float: left; 
      margin-left: 15px; 
      margin-top -50px;">
      Notifications : {{count($usersalert2)}}
  </h3>
  <div class="notificationcontainer">
      @php
         $usersid = Auth::id();
         $usersalert = DB::table('notifications')->where('userid', $usersid)->orderBy('created_at', 'desc')->get();
      @endphp

      @if(count($usersalert) > 0)
        @foreach ($usersalert as $item)
          <div class="notification">
             <h2 class="notiftitle">{{$item->type}}</h2>
             <h3>{{$item->message}}</h3>
             <a class="removenotif" data-id="{{$item->id}}" data-token="{{ csrf_token() }}"><i  class="crossnotif fas fa-times fa-sm"></i></a>
          </div>
        @endforeach
      @endif
  </div>
</div>
```

**JavaScript**

```
$(".removenotif").click(function(ev){
   var id = $(this).data("id");
   var token = $(this).data("token");
   $.ajax({
           url: 'deletenotif/'+id,
           type: 'DELETE',
           dataType: 'JSON',
           data: {
               "id":id,
               "_method": 'DELETE',
               "_token": token,
               },

           success: function (data) {
              console.log("it worked");
              $('#messageboxcon').load(document.URL +  ' #messageboxcon');
           },
           error: function (data) {
                 alert(data);
           }
});
```

Comment: Reload the new data in `success`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In the success callback, I would make use of the jQuery `.parents()` function.
In the context of the click event handler function, `$(this)` represents the "close notification element".
You need to remove the `<div>` with the `notification` class.
So I would do something like `$(this).parents('.notification').remove()`.

I'm not sure what you're trying to achieve with this:

```
$('#messageboxcon').load(document.URL +  ' #messageboxcon');
```

It will load the entire webpage in the messageboxcon `<div>` which is not what you want to achieve.

If you want to refresh the content, perform an AJAX call getting just the HTML for the notifications.

Just create a page (notifications.php) on server side that does just what you do initially:

```
      @php
         $usersid = Auth::id();
         $usersalert = DB::table('notifications')->where('userid', $usersid)->orderBy('created_at', 'desc')->get();
      @endphp

      @if(count($usersalert) > 0)
        @foreach ($usersalert as $item)
          <div class="notification">
             <h2 class="notiftitle">{{$item->type}}</h2>
             <h3>{{$item->message}}</h3>
             <a class="removenotif" data-id="{{$item->id}}" data-token="{{ csrf_token() }}"><i  class="crossnotif fas fa-times fa-sm"></i></a>
          </div>
        @endforeach
      @endif
```

Then in the success callback you remove the notification the user wants to delete for immediate feedback. And then make an AJAX call to refresh the notifications with something like that:

```
$('#notificationcontainer').load('notifications.php')
```

Comment: Hi, I made a notifications.blade.php in the layouts folder. I included it but when doing, $('#notificationcontainer').load('notifications.php') How do i locate it? Not very experienced with Javascript? so anything is a big help! :)

Comment: The notifications.php is just an example. I don't know which PHP framework you use but it doesn't really matter. And you don't need to be experienced with Javascript. You're using a templating system (blade) but you need to understand how to reference this view from your browser. Do you know which URL will lead to display that piece of HTML from your browser?

Comment: I made a function to update the content, the loop will only run once, If i have 3 notifications i can delete any of the 3 but trying to delete a second one nothing will happen. Not even in the console nothing shows up? would you know why?

Comment: I think yes but it really depends on what you did and I can't see it. If you mean that when the content is refreshed with the AJAX call, you can't remove the notification anymore it's normal.
You need to apply the click handler on the new elements. When you load the page the first time and do `$(".removenotif").click(<function>)`, it will only apply to the elements on the page. When you refresh the content dynamically, the new `.removenotif` elements won't have a click handler attach to them.

Comment: This happened before when I had the delete link to an ID, by realising and changing it to a class I fixed it. I don't think I explained properly. When loading the page I can delete 1 notification then if i try to delete a second nothing happens, the click event wont run. I can refresh the page and delete another, I could keep doing this until all notifications are deleted but I want to have it so I can delete all of them, go through the list. Thanks for your help so far, would you know a solution? :(

Comment: Fixed it, had to change the click event to $(document).on('click', '.removenotif', function(ev){

Answer (score 0):

in success do something like `$("#item-"+id).remove();`

Comment: As far as I can see, there's no elements with those kind of ids so this wouldn't really work in it's current form.

Comment: he can add it easily.

Comment: An answer should contain a proper code example with a proper description. Just posting a small piece of code that won't even work without additional changes (which isn't even mentioned) is not a proper example. Remember that we have no idea how experienced the OP or future visitors are. Don't assume they will understand what else to change.

Answer (score 0):

change this line

```
$('#messageboxcon').load(document.URL +  ' #messageboxcon');
```

to this :

```
$('#messageboxcon').load(document.URL +  '#messageboxcon');
```

in your success code.you have a extra space

Answer (score 0):

You need to create a new javascript function, in which, you'll get the data from notification table. The function should look like this:

```
function updateContent(){
$.ajax({
    url: 'n.php',
    type: 'GET',
    success: function (data) {
        console.log("get recent data in HTML");
        $('.notificationcontainer').html(data);
    },
    error: function (data) {
        console.log(data);
    }
});
```

}

And, code which is in **n.php** file

```
@php
$usersid = Auth::id();
$usersalert = DB::table('notifications')->where('userid', $usersid)->orderBy('created_at', 'desc')->get();
@endphp

@if(count($usersalert) > 0)
@foreach ($usersalert as $item)
    <div class="notification">
        <h2 class="notiftitle">{{$item->type}}</h2>
        <h3>{{$item->message}}</h3>
        <a class="removenotif" data-id="{{$item->id}}" data-token="{{ csrf_token() }}"><i  class="crossnotif fas fa-times fa-sm"></i></a>
    </div>
@endforeach
@endif
```

Now, just call that javascript function in **removenotif** click success method like this -

```
updateContent();
```

Comment: This worked great!, but it only works for the first in the loop. If I have 3 notifications i can delete any of the 3 I want but the ajax call will not run a second time?

Answer (score 0):

Create a duplicate of the notification container in a different file, let's say **not.php** 
Then Create a new Ajax with the URL as **not.php**
Then use the id of the notification container to get the data of the jquery. So it will be like a refresh.

Then create a button that will execute the new jQuery you have created on a click event.

So what you'll do is that, after your previous jQuery has deleted the notification, you'll make it cause a click even on the fresh button so that you wouldn't have to click it manually.
This will replace the old notification container with the new one.

Remember to link the jQuery file add aslo may want to add the jQuery code to the new file, that is **not.php** otherwise it will work only once since it won't get any ajax to use if you don't put it there as well

Comment: Hi, I tried this and it worked but it the ajax call runs once, say I have 4 notifications I can delete one of the four and have it refresh but when trying to delete a second one nothing happens, i can refresh the page and delete another one but I cant go through them and delete them all without having to refresh the page. Thanks for your reply would you know anything about this? :( cheers

Comment: You'll also have to put the jQuery refresh code in the **not.php** as well. Check my edited answer

Comment: Link the jQuery is file to the new file **not.php** as well